# nz-dropdown-menu called from *ngFor

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

I have and simple ngFor and I would like for each entry to have a button with dropdown and each menu item should call a different function for the specific item in the ngFor.

The code below works and the behaviour is what I expect.

```
<div *ngFor="let order of orders">

          <nz-dropdown>
              <button nz-button nz-dropdown [nzType]="'primary'" nzGhost>
                  <span>Almighty Dropdown</span><i nz-icon nzType="ellipsis"></i>
              </button>
              <ul nz-menu>
                  <li nz-menu-item (click)="fc1(order)">Function 1</li>
                  <li nz-menu-item (click)="fc2(order)">Function 2</li>
              </ul>
            </nz-dropdown>
</div>
```

However I get the error:

> ng-zorro-antd-core.js:658 [NG-ZORRO]: deprecated: 'nz-dropdown' Component > is going to be removed in 9.0.0. Please use 'nz-dropdown-menu' instead.

The code suggested by NG-ZORRO is:

```
<button nz-button nz-dropdown [nzDropdownMenu]="menu">Actions<i nz-icon nzType="down"></i></button>
<nz-dropdown-menu #menu="nzDropdownMenu">
  <ul nz-menu>
    <li nz-menu-item>
      <a>1st item</a>
    </li>
    <li nz-menu-item>
      <a>2nd item</a>
    </li>
    <li nz-menu-item>
      <a>3rd item</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nz-dropdown-menu>
```

**If I use code like NG-ZORRO suggest in the documentation, how can I pass the 'order' item from the ngFor to the 'clicks' on the submenus?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the `order` to the click function as your first example code, and it still works.

```
<div class="order" *ngFor="let order of orders">
    {{order.name}}
    <button nz-button nz-dropdown [nzDropdownMenu]="menu">Actions<i nz-icon nzType="down"></i></button>
    <nz-dropdown-menu #menu="nzDropdownMenu">
      <ul nz-menu>
        <li nz-menu-item>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="fc1(order)">1st item</a>
        </li>
        <li nz-menu-item>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="fc2(order)">2nd item</a>
        </li>
        <li nz-menu-item>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="fc3(order)">3rd item</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nz-dropdown-menu>
</div>
```

You can check this example out: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-start-hnxupx

Comment: I was defining `<nz-dropdown-menu #menu="nzDropdownMenu">` outside the ngFor